# Determine if Keycloak User has TOTP enabled

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, two-factor-authentication

I have a Single-Page Web-Application authenticating against Keycloak and letting Users enable TOTP in their Keycloak-Account-Page.

However I want the Client-Application to determine after login, if the authenticated User has 2-factor-authentication/TOTP enabled or not.

Is it possible to map this (boolean) information into the Tokens or userinfo Endpoint ... I haven't found any User Property, that contains this information.

The only Place I found it, was in Admin-REST-API `/auth/admin/realms/{realm}/users/{uuid}`, but the Client/End-user won't and shouldn't have access there:

```json
{
   ...
   totp: true,
   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible without customization.

You may want to add a custom protocol mapper and check for totp like this:

```java
keyclaokSession.userCredentialManager().isConfiguredFor(realm, user, OTPCredentialModel.TYPE)
```

[Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5WBb176YqKg) that explains the first steps.